# Adding css i js to python templates

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with including css and js files. My index page works fine, but when I try to put the same code to the detail page it doesn't work, **not even html** wich I wrote on detail.html, just the include files from master.html work. What can be the problem?

master.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="static/font.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="static/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="static/font-awesome.min.css "rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="static/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>     
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar" data-offset="0">
        {% include "header.html" %}
        {% include "carausel.html" %}
        {% block h1 %}{% endblock %}
        {% include "footer.html" %}
    <script src="static/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="static/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
    <script src="static/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

detail.html

```
{% extends "master.html"  %}
{% block h1 %}
<div class="box first">
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        {% for question  in latest_question_list %}
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                <div class="center">
                    <a href="{{ question.slug }}" i class="icon-credit-card icon-md icon-color1"></a>
                    <h4>{{ question.naslov }} </h4>
                    <p>{{ question.opis }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

```
{% endblock %}
{% block title  %} Detail {% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Question


def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.all()
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'papers/index.html', context)

def detail(request, slug):
     question = Question.objects.get(slug=slug)
     return render(request, 'papers/detail.html', {'question': question})
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include,  url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', 'papers.views.index', name='index'),
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
   url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w_-]+)/$', 'papers.views.detail', name='detail'),
]    

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: (I'm assuming django) what's in your urls.py concerning static?

Comment: what does your index.html look like?  it seems to be an issue of you not inheriting from the masterpage correctly.

Comment: index.html looks the same as detail.html and they extend master.html. Put the same code just to see if it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use absolute paths for all your static links.

```
 <link href="/static/....
 <script src="/static/...
```

Comment: you should probably use the [{% static %} template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#static)

Comment: The js and css are included, that works. But the question fields from the DB, do not apper.

Comment: Everything under {% block h1 %}{% endblock %}
doesn't appear

Comment: That appears to be a different question. But you don't have anything called `latest_question_list` coming from your detail view, so it's not surprising that nothing shows.

Comment: How should I write def detail in views? thanks, you are very helpfull.